# INSERT INTO MyTable (name, age, ...)

Tags: go

How can I structure this using the go [standard](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SQLInterface#executing-queries) sql package so others can read it?
I need to add many many fields.

```
result, err := db.Exec(
    "INSERT INTO MyTable (name, age, ...ALLLOOOT...) VALUES ($1, $2, ...ALLLOOOT...)",
    "gopher",
    27,
    ...ALLLOOOT...
)
```

EDIT: Bonus question, can you use something like this and extract field names from `db:"..."`?

```
type MyTable struct {
    Age   int64   `db:"age" json:"age"`
    Name  string  `db:"name" json:"name"`
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to do this, one of the ways I've done is create arrays of keys and values which you can then use to iterate and build up your query with placeholders.

You would then use variadic arguments to fill the placeholders.

It would look something like this

```
keys := []string{"your", "keys", ...}
values := []interface{}{1, "two", ...}
placeholders := make([]string, len(values))
for idx := range values {
    placeholders[idx] = "?"
}
query := fmt.Sprintf("INSERT INTO (%s) VALUES (%s)", strings.Join(keys, ", "), strings.Join(placeholders, ", "))

result, err := db.Exec(query, values...)
```

This playground shows something similar done with `fmt.Printf`

http://play.golang.org/p/NruF92EJqM

Comment: Nice :D See I knew I had to ask this first on stackoverflow before I start doing this myself and cram 100 fields into one line haha

Comment: Ps I added a bonus question if you are interested :)

Comment: To accomplish your bonus question it becomes a bit more complex but simply take a look at how how the `json` package does the tags check (e.g using reflection to get the tag fields). Or check out an example of what you're trying to accomplish... https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx